# Phalcon route groups 404 not working

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

I have URL's:

`site.com/sdfsdfsdfsd` - 404 Working

`site.com/ru/page/sdfasdfasfasdfsad` - not working, I get redirect to main page

```
$router->add('/', array(
  'module' => 'frontend',
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
  'lang' => 'md',
))->setName('default');

$router->add('/{lang:[' . $langsDefined . ']{2}+}(/?)', array(
  'module' => 'frontend',
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
  'lang' => 1,
))->setName('default_lang');
```

How I Can fix this?

```
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);
$router->notFound(array(
  "controller" => "Notfound",
  "action" => "index"
));
```

Method `NotFound` not working. I get redirect to main page!

Answer (score 0):

please notice namespace, you can try it as this:

```
$router->notFound(array(
    "module" => "frontend",
    "controller" => "Notfound",
    "action" => "index"
));
```